# How to get hash from array of hashes using a find?

Tags: ruby, arrays, select, hash

I have a hash set in my code that declares an elegibility scale:

```
eligibility_scale = [{family_size: 2, minimum_income: 20161, maximum_income: 38200},
                     {family_size: 3, minimum_income: 25393, maximum_income: 43000},
                     {family_size: 4, minimum_income: 30613, maximum_income: 47750},
                     {family_size: 5, minimum_income: 35845, maximum_income: 51600},
                     {family_size: 6, minimum_income: 41065, maximum_income: 55400},
                     {family_size: 7, minimum_income: 46297, maximum_income: 59250},
                     {family_size: 8, minimum_income: 51517, maximum_income: 63050}]
```

I'm trying to get the hash result using the `family_size` as the search parameter.

```
income_bracket = eligibility_scale.select{|h| h["family_size"] == 4 }
# Expecting: {family_size: 4, minimum_income: 30613, maximum_income: 47750}
```

After running this code I'm getting an empty array.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using select will return an array, first of all, so if your family_size is unique, you can just use `find`. Otherwise, use `select` in the same way, but expect to have an array of hashes returned.

Second of all, your hashes are using symbols, not string. Ideally, you're looking at writing something like this:

```
eligibility_scale.find { |i| i[:family_size] == 4 }
# => {family_size: 4, minimum_income: 30613, maximum_income: 47750}
```

This is assuming your family size is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Hash keys in the question are **symbols**, not **strings**.

You need to specify the key as symbol:

Replace following:

```
h["family_size"]
```

with:

```
h[:family_size]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your hash using the `key: value` syntax which is shorthand for `:key => value` - meaning the keys are symbols and not strings

```
eligibility_scale.select {|h| h[:family_size] == 4 }
```